# Is there a limit to the size of a variable in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have been adding sources to the included makefile for a project. As is, right now it runs perfectly. But if I uncomment the two lines indicated in the code, make spits out the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'engine/obj/graphics/window.o', needed by 'lib/engine.a'.  Stop.
```

I assume since it's just cutting off the start its something to with the length. If this is some limitation of the length of the variable is there any way around it?

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra

OUT_DIR=out
LIB_OUT_DIR=lib
APP_NAME=main
ENGINE_NAME=engine.a
EXECUTABLE=$(OUT_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
ENGINE_LIB=$(LIB_OUT_DIR)/$(ENGINE_NAME)

ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR=engine/obj
ENGINE_HEADER_DIR=engine/include
ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR=engine/src
ENGINE_SHADER_DIR=engine/shaders
APP_OBJECT_DIR=app/obj
APP_SOURCE_DIR=app/src

ENGINE_OBJECTS  = $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/window.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/shader_program.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/array.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/attribute_definition.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/abstract/buffer.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/simple_buffer.o
# ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/instance_buffer.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/graphics/index_buffer.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/math/vec2.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/math/vec3.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/math/vec4.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/math/mat4.o
ENGINE_OBJECTS += $(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/util/logging.o

ENGINE_SOURCES  = $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/window.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/shader_program.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/array.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/attribute_definition.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/abstract/buffer.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/simple_buffer.cpp
# ENGINE_SOURCES += $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/instance_buffer.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/index_buffer.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/math/vec2.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/math/vec3.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/math/vec4.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/math/mat4.cpp
ENGINE_SOURCES +=   $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/util/logging.cpp

ENGINE_SHADERS = \
    $(OUT_DIR)/vertexshader.glsl \
    $(OUT_DIR)/fragmentshader.glsl

APP_OBJECTS = \
    $(APP_OBJECT_DIR)/main.o

APP_SOURCES = \
    $(APP_SOURCE_DIR)/main.cpp

ENGINE_CXX_LIBS=-Wl,-Bstatic -lGLEW -lglfw3 -pthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -lGLU -ldl -lX11 -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXinerama
APP_CXX_LIBS=-L$(LIB_OUT_DIR) -l:$(ENGINE_NAME)

.PHONY: all build clean engine app run

all: clean build run

clean:
    rm -f $(OUT_DIR)/* $(LIB_OUT_DIR)/* $(ENGINE_OBJECTS) $(APP_OBJECTS)

build: engine app

run:
    cd $(OUT_DIR) && \
    ./$(APP_NAME)

engine: $(ENGINE_LIB) $(ENGINE_SHADERS)

app: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp $(ENGINE_SOURCES)
    $(CXX) -I$(ENGINE_HEADER_DIR)  -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(ENGINE_LIB): $(ENGINE_OBJECTS)
    ar rvs $@ $(ENGINE_OBJECTS)

$(OUT_DIR)/%.glsl: $(ENGINE_SHADER_DIR)/%.glsl
    cp -f $< $@

$(APP_OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(APP_SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp $(APP_SOURCES)
    $(CXX) -I$(ENGINE_HEADER_DIR) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(APP_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(APP_CXX_LIBS) $(ENGINE_CXX_LIBS)
```

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track.  There is a limit to size, but it's usually huge (64K or something like that), and you're nowhere near that...  You can use `$(info ENGINE_OBJECTS=$(ENGINE_OBJECTS))` to be sure that this is not the problem after declaring it.   I might look for hidden characters, and try using a `:=` instead of an `=` at the assignment stage...

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the size of a variable in `make` (except for the amount of memory in your system).  Your operating system will impose a maximum on the size of a command line that make can invoke, so if your variables are very large and you try to use them in a recipe it's possible the operating system will not allow it, but that's nothing to do with make and not the problem you're seeing here anyway.

I think the problem is that the file `$(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/graphics/instance_buffer.cpp` either doesn't exist or can't be accessed for some reason.

This rule is very broken:

```
$(ENGINE_OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(ENGINE_SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp $(ENGINE_SOURCES)
        $(CXX) -I$(ENGINE_HEADER_DIR)  -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

By adding the `$(ENGINE_SOURCES)` here you're saying that if any source file changes, *ALL* of the object files must be rebuilt.  I can't believe that's what you want (if you want to rebuild everything if any file changes you can just write a shell script that always rebuilds everything and you don't need make at all).

Not only that, but if make can't find or build *ALL* the source files, then this pattern rule won't match and make will keep looking to see if some other pattern rule will match.  In this case there are no others, so make just says "hey, I don't know how to build the file" (in this case, the `.../window.o` file).

Also if you run make with debugging (`make -d`) you'll see the problem (although the output is voluminous so you'll probably need to redirect it to a file and examine with an editor or less or something that lets you search and page back and forth).

You should remove `$(ENGINE_SOURCES)` from this rule.  Then likely make will fail with a more reasonable error, that it can't build `.../instance_buffer.o`.